# speex implementation in S60 3rd edition

Tags: c++, symbian, speex

anybody implement speex in 3rd edition..

please guide me....how to generate dll/lib with the help of speex api and use..?

b'coz it shows error for math.h stdlib.h basic c file

Thanks & Regards,
Rahul....

Comment: Please rephrase your question so that it can be answered without too much guessing: 1) What are you trying to do? 2) What is the problem? 3) What have you already tried yourself?

Answer (score 0):

try to include following line in your .mmp file

```
SYSTEMINCLUDE\epoc32\include\epoc32\include\libc
```

By the way, S60 3rd should provide build-in methods for text-to-speech, try to google it.